# NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<Menu:0x512be78>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
irb(main):001:0> hotel=Hotel.find(1)
  ←[1m←[36mHotel Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT  `hotels`.* FROM `hotels`  WHERE `hotels`.`hotel_Id` = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
=> #<Hotel hotel_Id: 1, hotel_Name: "Hotel Swosti", hotel_address: nil, hotel_location: "Bhubaneswar", hotel_contactNo: nil, crea
ted_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):002:0> hotel.menus
  ←[1m←[35mMenu Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `menus`.* FROM `menus`  WHERE `menus`.`hotel_id` = 1
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

irb(main):003:0> first_menu=Menu.new(:menu_item_name=>'Rajma',:price=>30,:item_type=>'Half')
=> #<Menu hotel_Id: nil, menu_item_id: nil, menu_item_name: "Rajma", price: 30, item_type: "Half", created_at: nil, updated_at: n
il>

irb(main):004:0> first_menu.hotel
=> nil

irb(main):005:0> hotel.menus=first_menu
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<Menu:0x512be78>
```

migration:
    create_table :menus,:id=>false do |t|
      t.integer 'hotel_Id'
      t.primary_key 'menu_item_id'
      t.string 'menu_item_name'
      t.integer 'price'
      t.string 'item_type'

```
end
add_index("menus","hotel_Id")
```

end
  end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add `first_menu` to `hotel.menus` association, you should do:

```
hotel.menus << first_menu
```

The error occurs because `Hotel#menus=` setter expects collection of `Menu` objects as parameter.

Comment: hotel.menus << first_menu.ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `hotel_id' This line of code is not working.

Comment: @Udaykumardas is there `hotel_id` column in your `menus` table? I bet there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

`hotel.menus` is a relation. The association that you used returns an array of hotel menus.

To get the first member, a single menu, you could use `hotel.menus.first`.

If you want to create a new menu for a hotel, you'll probably be better off using:

```
hotel.menus.build(menu_item_name: 'Rajma', price: 30, item_type: 'Half')
hotel.save!
```

or the `create` form - depending on what else you want to do with the hotel or the menu, before you save.